# How to analyze a JMeter jlt output (command-line non-GUI mode)?

Tags: jmeter

What is the meaning of the below output values from the jlt report run from command-line in non-GUI mode?

1. timeStamp
2. elapsed
3. bytes
4. sentBytes
5. grpThreads
6. allThreads
7. Latency
8. IdleTime
9. Connect

What sort of calculation metrics can we arrive at using the output of the jtl file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read [Listeners doc](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#csvlogformat)

> timeStamp - in milliseconds since 1/1/1970
>
> elapsed - in milliseconds
>
> connect - time to establish connection
>
> latency - time to first response
>
> IdleTime - number of milliseconds of 'Idle' time (normally 0)
>
> bytes - number of bytes in the sample
>
> sentBytes - number of bytes sent for the sample
>
> grpThreads - number of active threads in this thread group
>
> allThreads - total number of active threads in all groups

Comment: How can we calculate throughput based on these figures?

Comment: @variable execution time(last-first time)/samplers rows

Comment: execution time(last-first time) = sum of elapsed - isn't it?

Comment: @variable no, last-first timeStamp

Comment: and where do I get value of sampler rows? Is it sum of threads?

Comment: @variable you need to count the rows

Comment: But each row can have multiple threads - so how can I get the value? Also for elapsed you say it is in miliseconds -- but in your answer you have not mentioned what it means

Comment: Please can you provide what is the meaning of elapsed in your answer

Comment: @variable *elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response* see more in https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not be analyzing the raw .jtl results file, it is more handy to go for one of the following approaches:

1. Open the .jtl results file using a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice using JMeter GUI
2. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from the .jtl results file like:

   ```
   jmeter -g /path/to/your/results.jtl -o /path/to/folder/with/html/report
   ```
3. Generate tables (in CSV format) and charts using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv AggregateReport.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
4. Use online analysis solutions like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: What sort of meteics can we derive from the jtl file (without using listener)?

Comment: only those you listed

Comment: I mean how can we use these values to arrive at metrics

Comment: The majority of them are being [Calculated](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.html)